# Extract string between two '_'

Tags: regex, string, ant

I'm looking for an ANT regex to extract string between two `_` or between `abc_` and `_`
Below is the regex I'm trying, with no luck.

```
/xxx/xx_x/xxxx/abc_stringtoextract_x.x.zip
```

I need to fetch `stringtoextract`,

```
<propertyregex property="name"
     input="@{process}"
     regexp="(?<=abc_)(.*?)(?=\_)" 
     select="\1"
     casesensitive="false"/>
<echo>@{process}</echo>
```

Comment: Why do you need to check for `abc_`? If it's between `abc_` and `_`, the condition "between underscores" is already fulfilled.

Comment: If i check this regex in any regex edit tool, it's returning the string I wanted,  but not through ANT. Not sure where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.*abc_([^_]*)
```

Fixed the issue.

Comment: Any way to do this in a dataframe where a column has data with xyz_target_xyz?

Answer (score 2):

Replace `<` with the character entity `&lt;`. Also the result is saved in the `name` property specified in the `property` attribute, and not the `process` parameter, so you should `echo` the right result.

```
<propertyregex property="name"
    input="${process}"
    regexp="(?&lt;=abc_)(.*?)(?=\_)" 
    select="\1"
    casesensitive="false"/>
<echo>${name}</echo> <!-- instead of process -->
```

Comment: doesn't print any -   [echo] ${name}
when used @{process}, it just prints my original string. I don't see any results from the regex

Comment: <sequential>
                                <echo>@{process}</echo>
                                <propertyregex property="name"
                                input="@{process}"
                                regexp="(?&lt;=abc_)(.*?)(?=\_)"
                                select="\1"
                                casesensitive="false"/>
                                <echo>@{process}</echo>
                        <var name="process" unset="true"/>
                        <var name="name" unset="true"/>
                        </sequential>

Comment: I have some success with this  <propertyregex property="name"
                                input="@{process}"
                                regexp=".*abc_([^\.]*)"
                                select="\1"
                                casesensitive="false"/>
                                <echo>${name}</echo>
                        <var name="name" unset="true"/>
where, the results is stringtoextract_x, can you help me in excluding '_x' from results